# Extending the roof

Tags: extrude

[image]

How do I extend the edge in the correct way? I need to extend the roof 30 cm circa from the wall. But the extrude function only work on the xyz axis. No way I can extend the roof alont its own direction (inclined about 35°).

[image]

Comment: I went Local - then selected the edge - pressed G/G - and then C to extend beyond original position towards right. And it worked.

Comment: Hi, you should write an answer to your question in the answer section :)

Comment: Hello :). You can also use *Edge Slide tool* and disable *clamp* https://imgur.com/a/BtXeub3